# How are mem_available_percent and mem_used_percent are related in aws linux

Tags: amazon-ec2

How are mem_available_percent and mem_used_percent are related in aws linux

[image]

How can both available memory and used memory both be high. If used memory is high the should available memory be low?
Also used memory seems to vary over time but availabe memory seems to remain constant.

Comment: used memory will always be vary,because each process takes individual ram amount.So basically i dont see here a business related issue?

Answer (score 0):

Typically mem_used includes caches and buffers, which the OS can clear out at any moment if an application needs memory, so the memory taken up by the caches is available.

e.g. on my current system what I am seeing when I do `cat /proc/meminfo` I see almost no memory Free, but most of it (68%) is taken up by caches wich will be cleared as soon as an application needs memory.

```
   1   │ MemTotal:       16068712 kB
   2   │ MemFree:          178332 kB
   3   │ MemAvailable:   10290764 kB
   4   │ Buffers:          812504 kB
   5   │ Cached:         10203120 kB
   6   │ SwapCached:         1596 kB
   7   │ Active:          4852664 kB
   8   │ Inactive:       10034536 kB
```